# Vue JS and vite-plugin-ssr for Server or Client Side Rendering, depending on the user-agent, ideally to be hosted on AWS Lambda Edge

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, vite, aws-lambda-edge

I'm trying to use **vite-plugin-ssr** with **VueJS**, and dynamically decide whether to **SSR** or serve the Vue code for **client rendering**, according to the *User-Agent* passed to **isbot** (https://github.com/omrilotan/isbot).

The strategy is :

- If **isbot()** returns true, the returned HTML shall be SSR.
- Otherwise, the VueJS build files shall be returned for the client browser to achieve the rendering.

I found this interesting article https://dev.to/divporter/vue-serverless-side-rendering-with-aws-lambda-edge-1ep8 using **AWS Lambda Edge** to either achieve the SSR when a bot is detected, or let **CloudFront** source and return the VueJS files stored on **S3**, but it's a little bit outdated now.

I'm trying to use https://vite-plugin-ssr.com/ but cannot figure out how their Vue examples work. It seems either a page is rendered server side, or client side, but I can't find how to test the User-Agent upfront, and only then decide if the page shall be server side rendered or not.

Has anyone deployed such use case ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.